# HttpClient throwing "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" exception

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, .net-4.8

I have an old .net application (4.8) in which I'm using HttpClient to call an external service as follows :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
};
StringContent request = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObject, settings), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(Constant.ServiceUrl, request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Now When I run my app locally everything works perfectly fine, but when it is deployed I get the following error on my logs indicating that the Post failed :

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ....
```

I tried adding :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

But that didn't fix it, then I tried adding :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

But this also didn't fix it. Help please.

Comment: `await` instead of `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but that shouldn't be the cause of your problem. Between Client and Server, are there FireWalls that may need configuration?

Comment: Any idea what exactly might need to be changed on Firewalls?

Comment: _Maybe_ an excemption for your outgoing traffic? But that's really only a suspicion.

Comment: I checked and that's not the cause unfortunatelly.

Comment: Try using Wireshark to see if there is an issue with the TLS handshake. Look at Server and Client Hello, and see if there is a cipher mismatch. What version of Windows and .NET are both client and server running? Exact build numbers please.